# How do I use the MYSQL_TEST_LOGIN_FILE environment variable to change the mysql_config_editor file?

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL 5.7 on Ubuntu 16.04.

I want to set up a `mysql_config_editor` login path.  The default file for this information is `~/.mylogin.cnf`, but I would prefer to have it in the file `~/.config/mylogin.cnf`.

The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-config-editor.html) for `mysqli-config-editor` says

> To specify an alternate login path file name, set the MYSQL_TEST_LOGIN_FILE environment variable.

I tried doing this:

```
$ MYSQL_TEST_LOGIN_FILE=~/.config/mylogin.cnf

$ echo $MYSQL_TEST_LOGIN_FILE
/home/username/.config/mylogin.cnf

$ mysql_config_editor set --login-path=mysqldump --host=localhost --user=root --password
Enter password:
```

As you can see, I confirmed that the environment variable set correctly.  However, running the `set` command above created the file `~/.mylogin.cnf`, which I did not want, and did not create the file `~/.config/mylogin.cnf`, which I do want.

```
$ ls ~/.mylogin.cnf
/home/username/.mylogin.cnf

$ ls ~/.config/mylogin.cnf
ls: cannot access '/home/username/.config/mylogin.cnf': No such file or directory
```

How do I use the `MYSQL_TEST_LOGIN_FILE` environment variable to change the `mysql_config_editor` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evidently `mysql_config_editor set` spawns a shell subprocess, so to keep the environment variable available to it, you have to set it with `export`.  This works:

```
$ export MYSQL_TEST_LOGIN_FILE=~/.config/mylogin.cnf

$ echo $MYSQL_TEST_LOGIN_FILE
/home/username/.config/mylogin.cnf

$ mysql_config_editor set --login-path=mysqldump --host=localhost --user=root --password
Enter password: 

$ ls ~/.mylogin.cnf
ls: cannot access '/home/username/.mylogin.cnf': No such file or directory

$ ls ~/.config/mylogin.cnf
/home/username/.config/mylogin.cnf
```

Answer (score 0):

The login path file must be readable and writable to the current user, and inaccessible to other users.
Otherwise, `mysql_config_editor` ignores it, and client programs do not use it either.